# Using data from Axios.get() to render inside my React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, axios

Working on a React component where I want to display contact data that I pull from MongoDB via axios.get()...

axios.get(...) returns a Promise, although the promise is unresolved. I can pull the data in console.log,but can't do so for the component.

How do I resolve this promise to return an array, so that I could display the data inside the component?
End goal - Call user contact data from MongoDB and display it in a table for users

Code reference:
**axios.get() HTTP request**

```
app.get('/api/people/fetchall', requireLogin, async (req, res) => {

  const userContacts = await User.findOne({_id: req.user._id}, 'contacts');
  res.send(userContacts['contacts']);
  console.log(userContacts['contacts']);
 });
```

**Action creator**

```
export const fetchContacts = () => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.get('/api/people/fetchall');


    dispatch({type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data });
};
```

**React component**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';
import {fetchContacts} from '../../actions';
import axios from 'axios';

const fakedata = [{'name': 'Elliot Kang','company': 'Employableh','linkedin': 'linkedin.com/en/elliotkang7',
'department': 'PM','email': 'elliot@employableh.com'}];

class ContactDisplay extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state= {contacts: {},
      columns: [
        {title: 'Name', field: 'name'},
        {title: 'Company', field: 'company'},
        {title: 'Linkedin', field: 'linkedin'},
        {title: 'Department', field: 'department'},
        {title: 'Email', field: 'email'}
      ],

  }
}

  handleChange(event) {
      this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    }

  componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({contacts: fetchContacts()});
    }


  render() {
    return(
      <MaterialTable
      title='Contacts'
      columns = {this.state.columns}
      data = {fakedata}
      />
    );


  }
}

export default ContactDisplay;
```

Comment: Are you using redux to fetch the data?

Comment: No, not using redux. Should I? An answer with redux would be fine too. Open to new ways of fetching data, although I would like to keep axios.get()

Comment: where is the reducer ?? and map to prop

Comment: redux, u need to set data in reducer. not `this.setState({contacts: fetchContacts()});`